# ASP Calendar control to change background color code behind C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

If dates are available in database table, then the Calendar background color should be changed as a red color base on available event dates in a SQL table.
Below is my design code.

```
<asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" OnSelectionChanged="Calendar1_SelectionChanged">
</asp:Calendar>
Selected Date: <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" ></asp:Label>

 <br />
 <br />

  <asp:GridView ID="gv_Regdetails" runat="server" AllowSorting="True"
                AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="mGrid"
                Width="900px" PageSize="50">
                <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sno">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="30px" />
                        <ItemStyle CssClass="th" HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="30px" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="EventName" HeaderText="EventName">
                        <ItemStyle CssClass="th" HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="30px" />
                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="30px" Height="25px" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title">
                        <ItemStyle CssClass="th" HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="30px" />
                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="30px" Height="25px" />
                    </asp:BoundField>

                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description">
                        <ItemStyle CssClass="th" HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="30px" />
                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="30px" Height="25px" />
                    </asp:BoundField>

                </Columns>
                <EmptyDataTemplate>
                    <center>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label12" runat="server" Text="No Data avaliable for selected dates"
                                        ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label></center>
                </EmptyDataTemplate>
            </asp:GridView>
```

Below is my c# code and I am writing my logic in Calendar1_DayRender method.

```
protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    Label1.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();
    bo.Para1 = Label1.Text;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = bl.Get_detailsbydate(bo);
    gv_Regdetails.DataSource = dt;
    gv_Regdetails.DataBind();
}
protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = bl.Get_detailsbydate(bo);
    string dates = dt.Rows[0]["EventDate"].ToString();

 //   if (e.Day.Date == dates)
//    { 
 //           e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
 //           e.Cell.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
//    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   dt = bl.Get_detailsbydate(bo);
   string dates = dt.Rows[0]["EventDate"].ToString();// Confirm if you  EventDate is in a same format to calendar

   if (e.Day.Date == dates)
   { 
        e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
        e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
   }


}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)